# Change textbox value and button name when the form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Im trying to create a very simple clock in/clock out system. Try to see the html code below.

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="work" name="work" />
<input type="submit" value="Clock In" name="submit" />
<?php 'some php code here' ?>
</form>
```

What I wanted to achieve is that whenever I click the submit button and form submits the data, the value of the textbox and the submit button would change. When you click it for the first time both would change to 'break/Clock Out', then when clicked again it would change to 'work/Clock In'. How is it possible? I believe it would require js but have no idea of the code yet. Tried searching anywhere but no luck. Hoping someone here would be able to help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using Ajax to submit the form?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't really the best site for looking for tutorial help so you may get downvoted and closed based on this question. There is quite a bit of information online that will show you how to do what you are looking to accomplish - including the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/). Try searching for basic tutorials first online, then try to apply them to your problem... if you have *coding related issues* please come back :)

Comment: im using php to submit the form.

Comment: i dont need a tutorial. i just need a sample.

Comment: _“im using php to submit the form”_ – no, you are not …

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've correctly understood.
You don't need to make a post submission with this form?
Just change values?

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if($("input[name='work']").val()=='work')
            {
            $("input[name='work']").val('break');
            $("input[name='submit']").val('Clock out');
          }
         else
            {
            $("input[name='work']").val('work');
            $("input[name='submit']").val('Clock in');
          }
        });
```

Jquery needed in this example obviously.